# Running tasks concurrently from AsyncIterator with limit by threads and task id

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, concurrency, limit

I have to write function on JS/TS (without additional packages), which has 3 arguments: handler (async function), tasks (AsyncIterator) and limit of threads (number, or Infinity). Here example of a task:

```
// js
const task = {
id: 1,
type: 'init',
};
```

Handler is the function, which execute each task. I have to execute as much tasks concurrently as I can:

- within limit of threads.
- I can't execute concurrently 2 tasks with the same id from ArrayIterator. There can be 2 tasks with same id, but different types, e.g. 'init', 'cleanup', etc.
- tasks with same id must execute in proper order from ArrayIterator

Tasks array can have infinite length.

I found many examples with running tasks concurrently, e.g. below. But I don't know how to limit them by task id.

```
async function limit(tasks, handler, concurrency) {
  const results = [];

  async function runTasks(tasksIterator) {
    for (const [index, task] of tasksIterator) {
      try {
        await handler(task);
      } catch (error) {
        results[index] = new Error(`Failed with: ${error.message}`);
      }
    }
  }

  const workers = new Array(concurrency)
    .fill(tasks.entries())
    .map(runTasks);

  await Promise.allSettled(workers);

  return results;
}
```

Comment: There are no threads in Javascript.  I assume you just mean multiple async methods..?

Comment: Hi! I mean running tasks with limit (or without limit) asynchronously. I'm a newbie, so maybe I used not completely correct words to describe my task:)

Comment: Ok, I think I know what your after.. I'll see if I can knock up a simple snippet.   Your `limit` function based on your description is missing the async handler..

Comment: It was just for an example. I mixed a lot of variations with syncIterator, and it was one of them. Now I added handler, but it is not the main problem:( In ArrayIterator I can't use entries() and I still don't know how to hold tasks with ID of running now tasks without holding all queue.

Comment: Ok, deleted my answer as it seems to be off base.  But you could use similar ideas, to make sure ids run in series you could maybe use some sort of bucket system, and when a bucket count is equal to concurrency flush the buckets, but you will also need pause this bucket filling while flushing to prevent ids back back filling it.